# Capture curl header and response in environment variable

Tags: bash, curl, response

If I run a curl command like so:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d $JSON $URL
```

in stdout I get both the headers and the response. But if I try to capture them both, using

```
foo=$(curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d $JSON $URL)
echo $foo
```

this prints only the response, without the headers. Is it possible to also capture the headers in the same environment variable?

Comment: Can't replicate. This captures the header and response: `a=$(curl -is http:// www.netscape.com/); echo "$a"`. Remember to use double-quotes around `$a` to retain newlines.

Comment: Ooga is correct, without the quotes you lose \n. Since HTTP headers contain \r\n, just the CR is left. It prints the headers, moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, and then prints the next line over the output.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too and it was a serious head scratcher. I solved it by piping to `tr` and deleting `\r` characters like so:

```
foo=$(curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d $JSON $URL | tr -d '\r')
echo $foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around your variable.

```
$ foo=$(curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d $JSON $URL)
$ echo "$foo"
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 16:38:16 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```